# Unexpected output of string function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm writing code in Python 3 - or trying to - that takes in a string of braces such as '{{]]' and looks for an adjacent pair of braces which is either '[' followed immediately by ']', or '{' followed immediately by '}', or '(' followed immediately by ')'. It returns the first pair it finds, or False if it doesn't find any. To that end, I wrote some code:

```py
# write a function that scans a sequence of braces to find a "married pair", or else returns false if there is none.  
def find(mystring):
    for x in mystring[0:-1]:
        y=mystring[mystring.index(x)+1:][0]
        if (x == '[' and y == ']') or (x == '{' and y == '}') or (x == '(' and y == ')'):
            return x,y
        else:
            continue
    return False
```

So OK it works when I try the find function on the string `({})`. It returns `('{','}')` as expected. But when I try find `('{{}}')` it unexpectedly returns `False`. Running `([()])` unexpectedly returns `False`. `([{}])` returns `True` as expected.

What is going on here?

Comment: `mystring.index(x)` doesn't return the index you're looking at. It returns the _first_ index of the given character. So when you're at the second `{` character, `index(x)` returns 0. If you're using indexes while iterating, use `enumerate`.

Comment: And it was comparing for '([()])' ( to [ instead of ( to ), got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mystring.index(x)` doesn't return the index you're looking at. It returns the *first* index of the given character. So when you're at the second `{` character of `{{}}`, `index(x)` returns 0. If you're using indexes while iterating, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

A fixed version could be like this:

```
def find(mystring):
    for i,x in enumerate(mystring[:-1]):
        y = mystring[i+1]
        if (x == '[' and y == ']') or (x == '{' and y == '}') or (x == '(' and y == ')'):
            return x,y
    return False
```

Answer (score 3):

`.index()` returns the FIRST index of the occurrence of that char, so when you have more then 1, you get the wrong y.

you can pair adjacent chars using `zip` like this:

```py
def find(mystring):
    pairs = zip(mystring, mystring[1:])
    for x, y in pairs:
        if (x == '[' and y == ']') or (x == '{' and y == '}') or (x == '(' and y == ')'):
            return x, y
        else:
            continue
    return False


print(find('({})'))
print(find('{{}}'))
print(find('([()])'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def find_married_braces(s):
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        a, b = s[i], s[i+1]
        if (a == '(' and b == ')') or (a == '[' and b == ']') or (a == '{' and b == '}'):
            return i, i+1
    return False


print(find_married_braces('{{]]'))
print(find_married_braces('{{}}'))
print(find_married_braces('([()])'))
print(find_married_braces('([{}])'))
```

## Output

```
False
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(2, 3)
```